# Modificar variables en un Metodo Asincrono

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Necesito obtener un valor de una base de datos de Firebase que se me devuelve en un metodo onComplete(), el problema es que a su vez necesito obtener ese valor para luego modificarlo y subirlo a la misma base de datos en el onCreate(), y lo que me sucede es que ese valor no me es devuelto correctamente, sino que se sube antes de que termine el onComplete() y por lo tanto no obtiene el dato esperado sino siempre un 0 al cual le sumo 1, cuando corro una segunda vez si funciona, solo falla la primera vez. Como podría hacer para obtener el valor y subirlo correctamente? Muchas gracias!
Codigo:

```
private int obtenerIndicador(final String nombre) {
        db.collection(nombre.toUpperCase()).orderBy("indicador", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                //Log.d("db", document.get("indicador").toString());
                                resultado = Integer.valueOf(document.get("indicador").toString());

                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("db", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }

                });

        return resultado;

    }
```

Lo llamo desde un onClick en el onCreate()

```
user.put("indicador", obtenerIndicador(nombreEditText.getText().toString().toUpperCase()) + 1);


                    db.collection(nombreEditText.getText().toString().toUpperCase())
                            .add(user)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.w("TAG", "Error adding document", e);
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es que en vez de retornar el resultado en la función, usar una variable de la clase que se posiciona en onComplete cuando lo hayas recibido, y guardar el resultado en otra variable de la clase, por ejemplo. Y en el otro lado, esperar a que la variable indicadora esté levantada para ir a buscar el resultado y operar con él. Vas a tener que montarte un AsyncTask, o algo así.

Comment: Mira cómo crear un callback.  De esta menera, al completar finalizar el onComplete, llamas al callback y ejecutará lo que necesites.  (Es una interfaz con un método)

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas,  pero alguien me podría explicar como hacerlo? Ya que investigué y no logro dar en el clavo. Saludos!

Comment: @ManuelMato esta en lo correcto... he aquí un link explicando una forma de hacerlo: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/asynchronous-synchronous-callbacks-java/

Comment: También se puede lograr utilizando interfaces: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/callback-using-interfaces-java/?ref=lbp

Comment: Al fin lo solucione usando un AsyncTask modificado, luego probaré la respuesta de Manuel haber que tal

Comment: Una soluciòn es usar un Asynctask y obtener el valor en onPostExecute() , otra forma es como lo indica @ManuelMato , recuerda que si alguna respuesta ayudo a solucionar la problematica planteada en el problema puedes marcarla como soluciòn

Comment: La verdad no tuve tiempo de asignar la recompensa ni probar las respuestas, luego probare lo que contestaron, al final lo solucione con un AsyncTask modificado por que a su vez dentro de este tenia un onComplete() que complicaba las cosas, saludos y gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

Para resolverlo, primero necesitas crear la interfaz:

```
interface DatabaseCallback {
    void onFinish(Integer result);
}
```

Después creas una variable en el scope de la Activity:

```
private DatabaseCallback databaseCallback;
```

y la inicializas en el onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initDatabaseCallback();
}

private void initDatabaseCallback() {
    databaseCallback = result -> {
        // do something
    };
}
```

El doSomething se sustituye por la operación que quieres realizar cuando finalice el método obtenerIndicador:

```
private void initDatabaseCallback() {
        databaseCallback = result -> {
            user.put("indicador", result + 1);

            db.collection(nombreEditText.getText().toString().toUpperCase())
                    .add(user)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.w("TAG", "Error adding document", e);
                        }
                    });
        };
    }
```

Y por último, el método obtener indicador no devuelve nada y el resultado se pasa a través del método onFinish del callback en el onComplete:

```
 int resultado = Integer.valueOf(document.get("indicador").toString());
 databaseCallback.onFinish(resultado);
```

Al final obtenerIndicador queda así:

```
private void obtenerIndicador(final String nombre) {
    db.collection(nombre.toUpperCase()).orderBy("indicador", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            //Log.d("db", document.get("indicador").toString());
                            int resultado = Integer.valueOf(document.get("indicador").toString());
                            databaseCallback.onFinish(resultado);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("db", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que la implementación de un listener, no significa su ejecución en ese momento, sino cuando se deba notificar un evento FUTURO, pues generalmente se usan para eventos que pueden ser tardados y por lo cual, se realizan en segundo plano, en otro hilo de ejecución, por eso es que al momento de retornar el valor, aún no se ha hecho la asignación. Entonces puedes pasar tu listener como argumento de tu método obtenerIndicador para que en la implementación de este listener dejes programado lo que harás al obtener el resultado, en pocas palabras, sólo es refactorizar un poco el código, como se muestra a continuación:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String nombre = nombreEditText.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
    OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> listener = new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            //Log.d("db", document.get("indicador").toString());
                    putIndicador(Integer.valueOf(document.get("indicador").toString()));
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("db", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    }
    obtenerIndicador(nombre, listener);
}

private void obtenerIndicador(final String nombre, OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> listener) {
    db.collection(nombre.toUpperCase()).orderBy("indicador", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(listener);
}

private void putIndicador(int indicador) {
    user.put("indicador", indicador);
    db.collection(nombreEditText.getText().toString().toUpperCase())
    .add(user)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Error adding document", e);
        }
    });
}
```

PD: Como recomendación, si tu código comienza a ser muy largo, debería ser refactorizado en varios métodos que realicen una sola acción, lo digo por si tienes más código en tu método onCreate(), o en el onClick(), así como refactoricé lo que haces desde la línea user.put(...)